# Negative impact on performance for properties that are high up on the prototype chain.solution?

Tags: javascript

So, I am just reading thru the mozilla docs - brushing up, and I came across this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Performance

```
Performance

The lookup time for properties that are high up on the prototype chain can have a
negative impact on performance, and this may be significant in code where 
performance is critical.
```

I get this. Makes perfect sense - BUT, I was always under the assumption creating re-usable code by borrowing/extending prototypes was a good thing. So, my question is.

IF your application is large enough, and given the above statement - what patterns/O.O approach is most appropriate when coding in javascript for these larger applications?

Comment: In a large application, most code does not need to be fast. Do you have an example of objects with a long prototype chain whose property lookups need to be blazingly fast? I bet no. Chain your prototypes as it fits in your application structure, come back if these are getting actually performance-critical.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I was just asking in a general sense.

Comment: you can call, apply, or bind a deeply-rooted function to the local scope for faster execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very surprised if this performance became an issue in all but the most real-time applications (such as, perhaps, the growth of HTML5/JS based games), so "creating re-usable code by borrowing/extending prototypes" is still a "good thing". I'm sure someone here will [warn you about premature optimisation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

However, if you did have the need, there's the argument that you're better off making use of [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) anyway.

JavaScript being what it is can also be structured in different ways to allow inheritance like features without making use of the prototype chain. For example you can dynamically extend a copy of a base object in a "constructor" function to push the super and sub-class functionality into same object rather than rely on prototypical inheritance. Note that these sort of alternatives will have their own trade offs (for example, dynamically creating object inheritance as I've described would involve more memory as you're copying everything around so much).

Comment: That is what I was thinkng in terms of your $Super reference. I was just curious if there was a pre-ordained way for larger applications. I appreciate your reply.

Comment: Not that I'm really aware of. Making use of prototypes is the most common way I've seen. But as I alluded to in my answer, one of the blessing/curses of javascript is there are many, many ways to achieve the same results. I'm sure if you looked through various major libraries out there, you'd see a multitude of different ways. That being said, it would be interesting to see if anyone else chimes in with an alternative perspective.

Comment: I think two things that most people would agree on though (especially with a language as dynamic/flexible as JavaScript), is that consistency  is far more important than any particular design pattern and that readable, maintainable code is far more valuable than slightly more performant code.